# What are the upper and lower sets of teeth are called?

Tags: anatomy, nomenclature, teeth

I'd like to know the correct term for the a group of teeth in the skull and jax (mandible) Not the specific types of teeth i.e molars, incisors, carnassials, canines etc but what a set of teeth get referred to. the upper teeth.

Answer (score 7):

Upper teeth: maxillary teeth 
Lower teeth: mandibular teeth

> The term, "maxillary", is given to teeth in the upper jaw and "mandibular" to those in the lower jaw.

If you search these terms you will find many references.
You can start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_anatomy) which has many cross references.